# Exception Info: System.IO.FileLoadException when running exe on production

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, console-application, octopus-deploy

I have created one import console application in ***.net framework 4.5*** .
These are the packages that I have used in my application :

```
<packages>
  <package id="CSVReader" version="3.8.1" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="EnterpriseLibrary.Common" version="6.0.1304.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="EnterpriseLibrary.Data" version="6.0.1304.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="log4net" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="OctoPack" version="2.0.18" targetFramework="net40" />
</packages>
```

The console application is working absolutely fine on my local system but when I  try to deploy it on server and run the exe it is throwing me this error:

```
Faulting application name: app.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x58f0c4a0
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.23796, time stamp: 0x59029714
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x000000000001a06d
Faulting process id: 0x258
Faulting application start time: 0x01d2df846c72d791
Faulting application path: D:\filePath\app.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll

Application: app.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.FileLoadException
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(System.Reflection.RuntimeModule, Int32, IntPtr*, Int32, IntPtr*, Int32, System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ObjectHandleOnStack)
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(System.Reflection.RuntimeModule, Int32, System.RuntimeTypeHandle[], System.RuntimeTypeHandle[])
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32, System.Type[], System.Type[])
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(System.Reflection.CustomAttributeRecord, System.Reflection.MetadataImport, System.Reflection.Assembly ByRef, System.Reflection.RuntimeModule, System.Reflection.MetadataToken, System.RuntimeType, Boolean, System.Object[], System.Collections.IList, System.RuntimeType ByRef, System.IRuntimeMethodInfo ByRef, Boolean ByRef, Boolean ByRef)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(System.Reflection.RuntimeModule, Int32, Int32, System.RuntimeType, Boolean, System.Collections.IList, Boolean)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly, System.RuntimeType)
   at System.Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(System.Reflection.Assembly, System.Type, Boolean)
   at System.AppDomain.GetTargetFrameworkName()
```

Does anyone knows what could be the possible reason for this error? 
Thanks in advance .

Comment: Can you show the code where you handle any file/s?

Comment: Checked Permissions?

Comment: Look at the all the files (especially exe and dll) in your local bin folder. Compare that to all of the files on your production machine. Are any on the local machine that are missing from the production machine?

Comment: Do you have .NET 4.5 installed on the server? Can you post the code that runs on startup?

Comment: @Jamiec Yes permissions are already granted.

Comment: @w69rdy yes i have .Net 4.6.1 installed on server , my other exe's are working fine even though they are on same .net framework.

Comment: @mjwills I use octo-deployment for deploying , not the manual copy and paste to server. And as far I can see , all the Dll's and exe are there. The issue might be of difference in versioning of dll.

Comment: right-click and run as administrator. Rule that out first..

Comment: @ManxJasonI have tried this aswell but not working.

Comment: `And as far I can see` - so you have listed the files, side by side, and they are the same? *Exactly* the same?